# RoundTrip failure: stream error: stream ID 1; PROTOCOL_ERROR in net/http golang

Tags: go, http2

I am trying to stream a file in chunks from client to server (grpc) and then from grpc server send that file to another server by http post request. But I am keep getting this error when I try to send chunks of file to the other server by HTTP POST request. The transmission between client and server (grpc) is fine

Any idea what is this error and how to fix it ?. Please help me

```
{"level":"info","ts":"2020-02-11T03:00:07Z","msg":"http2: Transport received RST_STREAM stream=1 len=4 ErrCode=PROTOCOL_ERROR"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2020-02-11T03:00:07Z","msg":"RoundTrip failure: stream error: stream ID 1; PROTOCOL_ERROR"
```

Comment: This is either an issue with the HTTP/2 server or a bug in Go. [Set GODEBUG](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-overview) to see details and [create an issue](https://golang.org/s/http2bug) if you believe it's a bug in Go.

Comment: @Peter That message is come from GODEBUG. I suspect that something went wrong while go http2 trying to read frames